# Unable to find the error in the code I wrote for a question on loops in C++. Could anyone point it out?

Tags: c++, math

a beginner at coding here.
I was practising loops(c++) when I stumbled upon this problem:-
**Write a program in C++ to find the perfect numbers between 1 and 500. (6,28 and 496)

Perfect number: It is a positive integer that is equal to the sum of its proper divisors. The smallest perfect number is 6, which is the sum of 1, 2, and 3.**
I wrote the following code:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n=2; //test numbers from 2 to 500.
    int div=1; //divisor for n.
    int sum=0; //sum of divisors which divide n.
    while (n<=500) {
        while (div<n){ //if div divides n, then it will added to sum and incremented, else only incremented.
            if (n%div==0){
                sum=sum+div;
                div++;
            } else{
                div++;
            }
        }
        if (sum==n){
            cout<<n<<" is a perfect number."<<endl;
            n++;
        } else{
            n++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The code is supposed to print that 6, 28 and 496 are perfect numbers.
But instead, it's not printing anything. Haven't been able to find the error yet after checking for 30+ minutes.
Could anyone point out the error?

Comment: Create sub function (as `bool isPerfectNumber(int n)`), currently, your variables (`div`/`sum`) are not re-initialized...

Comment: `sum ` and `div`never get back to `0` and `1`

Comment: Variant of [Sieve_of_Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to re-initialize some variables in your loop.

`for` seems more appropriate than `while` here.

Create sub function also help to "identify" scope.

```
#include <iostream>

bool isPerfectNumber(int n)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (int div = 1; div != n; ++div) {
        if (n % div == 0) {
            sum += div;
        }
    }
    return sum == n && n > 0;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 2; i != 501; ++i) {
        if (isPerfectNumber(i)) {
            std::cout << n << " is a perfect number." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool perfect_num(int x);

int main() {
    int m, n, x;
    cout << "input the range m, n: " << "\n";
    cin >> m >> n;
    for (x = m; x <= n; ++x) {
        if (perfect_num(x)) {
            cout << x << " ";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

bool perfect_num(int x) {
    bool flag = false;
    //initialize
    int sum = 0, i;
    //loop 1 to x
    for (i = 1; i < x; ++i) {
        //judge whether is the factor
        if (x % i == 0) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    //update flag
    flag = (sum == x);
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

//judge function
bool isPerfectNum(int num){
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < num; ++i) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            tmp += i;
        }
    }
    return tmp == num;
}

int main(){
    cout << "Perfect Number contains: ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= 500; ++i){
        if (isPerfectNum(i)) {
            cout << i << "  ";
        }
    }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

at the end of your first loop, you should bring back div and sum to their default value.

```cpp
int main() {
    int n=2; //test numbers from 2 to 500.
    int div=1; //divisor for n.
    int sum=0; //sum of divisors which divide n.
    while (n<=500) {
        while (div<n){ //if div divides n, then it will added to sum and incremented, else only incremented.
            if (n%div==0){
                sum=sum+div;
                div++;
            } else{
                div++;
            }
        }
        if (sum==n){
            cout<<n<<" is a perfect number."<<endl;
            n++;
        } else{
            n++;
        }
        div = 1; // you should bring them back here.
        sum = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would say, reduce scope of `div`/`sum` instead. so initialization is only done at the begining of the scope.

Comment: Yes `div` and `sum` should be "reinitialized" but your suggestion is possibly the worst one could advise. See Jarod's comment on the question.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm not experienced and educated enough in coding to understand the sub-function you suggested, could you kindly elaborate on it?

Comment: @AyushGupta: I have added an answer with sub functions.

Comment: @YSC, Of course, it's best to reinit them in the scope. I just wanted to show why it's not working.